# Using monetary fields in JHipster

Tags: reactjs, jhipster

Regarding monetary fields in @jhipster, I guess BigDecimal is the advised type ?

And what is the best way to handle monetary input fields so that decimal places are kept to 2 etc - any suggested libraries? (for React.js)

Maybe using the 'pattern' option for AvField's is the way ?

Comment: react.js framework

Comment: Using a pattern would work in many cases. But it's hard to get it right as the decimal separator differs for each language and the number of decimal places differs from currency. If there is something that uses icu data that would be best. http://site.icu-project.org/home